# Intern Product involving the product of a transformation and it's adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, in the proof of the statement "For every transformation $A$ between finite dimension vector spaces, $AA^*$ is non-negative" there's the following line, which i can't get: $$\langle{A^*Av,v}\rangle=\langle{Av,Av}\rangle$$
I see how this implies $A^*A$ being non-negative. But, why is this statement true?

Comment: What's the definition of $A^*$?

Comment: $A^*$ is the adjoint transformation. $$\langle{Av,w}\rangle=\langle{v,A^*w}\rangle$$ By definition.

Comment: Right. And that's equivalent to $<w,Av> = <A^*w,v>$. (Exactly why it's equivalent depends on whether this is a real or complex vector space...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hm, i see, and this implies the statement somehow?

Comment: "Somehow": The equality you ask about is a special case.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, i see that now. Thanks for making things clear!